# First-class class/record instantiation 

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of records/classes, and I `map` over that sequence with `new` and expect to get a sequence of instances of those records/classes. I know `new` is a special form, but I was expecting Clojure to do The Right Thing in this case.

But this does not work:

```
(map new [SomeClass1 SomeClass2 SomeClass3])
```

Neither does this.

```
(map #(new %) [SomeClass1 SomeClass2 SomeClass3])
```

Similar code works in [Factor](http://factorcode.org/).

```
{ SomeClass1 SomeClass2 SomeClass3 } [ new ] map
```

What would be the right way to do this in Clojure? (I expect it won't involve `Class.newInstance` ugliness.)

**Edit:**

The following works, but is perhaps slower than necessary. (I don't know for sure. I would appreciate some information on this.)

```
(map #(eval `(new ~%)) [SomeClass1 SomeClass2 SomeClass3])
```

Also I am looking for something more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because special-formes are well... special they are not first class and don't compose as proper functions do, you can solve this with eval and macros:

a solution using eval:

```
(defn fnew [c] (eval `(new ~c))) 
hello.core> (map fnew ['Exception 'java.lang.String])
(#<Exception java.lang.Exception> "")
```

and a version that takes arguments to the constructors:

```
(defn fnew [c] (eval `(new ~@c))) 

hello.core> (map fnew ['(Exception) '(java.lang.String "I am a contructor argument")])
(#<Exception java.lang.Exception> "I am a contructor argument")

(map fnew [ [Exception] [(class "foo") "I am a contructor argument"]])
(#<Exception java.lang.Exception> "I am a contructor argument")
```

and here is a macro example

```
hello.core> (defmacro newify [classes] (apply vector (for [c classes] `(new ~c))))
#'hello.core/newify

hello.core> (macroexpand '(newify [java.lang.String Exception]))
[(new java.lang.String) (new Exception)]

hello.core>  (newify [java.lang.String Exception])
["" #<Exception java.lang.Exception>]
```

The macro version is likely more efficient while the eval version is more flexible.

Comment: I would like to keep the mapping logic outside. The broader context of my question is dealing with class/record instantiation in a truly first class fashion.

Comment: +1. A sidenote: When you edit your question to add something new, the new text should go below the original text. Or at least use `EDIT` tag to make it obvious what was added. (In this case, you added the `eval` part _after_ I made the `eval` edit to my question.)

Answer (score 1):

As `new` is a special form, one of the solution to make it work like first class would be use the clojure low level calls like:

```
(map #(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeConstructor %1 (into-array [])) [String])
```

This may lead to the performance problems of Reflection hence the macro based solution are prefered over this.